# readline() как обработать команды типа /n

Tags: python, readline

Столкнулся с проблемой, что при выводе из файла `context.txt` командой `readline()` Вместе со всем текстом вместо перевода на новую строку выводит команду `/n` как текст, в чем проблема?

Условно говоря в текстовом файле содержится одна строка с текстом: `"Осень /n Зима /n Весна /n Лето"`. И я хочу чтобы когда файл прочитал файл, он вывел его как:

```
Осень
Зима
Весна
Лето
```

Comment: покажи код вывода

Comment: Условно говоря в текстовом файле содержится одна строка с текстом: "Осень /n Зима /n Весна /n Лето" И я хочу чтобы когда файл прочитал файл, он вывел его как:
Осень
Зима
Весна
Лето

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Во-первых управляющий символ переноса строки - `\n`, а не `/n`. Во-вторых текст `\n` из файла (или например введенный через `input()`) - это два отдельных символа, которые считываются как строка `'\\n'`. Перевод строки `'\n'` - это один символ. Если нужно, чтобы `\n` из файла обрабатывались как перевод строки, после считывания делайте замену `'\\n'` на `'\n'`:

```
line = file.readline()
line = line.replace('\\n', '\n')
```

Если нужно чтобы текст `/n` тоже обрабатывался как перенос строки, аналогично добавьте замену `'/n'` на `'\n'`.

Comment: или сделать замену `line.replace('/n', '\n')`

Comment: @eri, добавил..

Comment: это было моментально)

Comment: Спасибо, да про разницу / \ я напутал, прошу извинения. Помогли

Comment: @МаратАминов если ответ помог, вы можете отметить его принятым - поставить галку слева от ответа.

Comment: @eri, просто сначала отредактировал, потом появился ваш коммент)

Answer (score 0):

Вариант с построчным чтением файла и удалением пробелов и символов перевода каретки ( в том числе табуляции в конце строки) :

```
file = open("test.txt")

for line in file.readlines():
    print(line.rstrip())
```

Вариант считать строки из файла сразу в `List<string>`, так же с удалением пробелов и всего прочего в конце строки :

```
file = open("test.txt")

temp = [line.rstrip() for line in file]
print(temp)
```